# PHP: How to traverse an associative-array by having a child's reference?

Tags: php, arrays, reference, traversal, levels

I have a function declaration like this:

```
function func(&$array){//do something};
```

Then I have an array like this:

```
$people[gender][singlePerson][property]=>value
```

I call my function this way:

```
func($people[man][person1]);
```

In my function now I have the parameter $array that contain the reference to:

```
$people[man][person1]
```

Now the problem...
How can i traverse the reference to get the position

```
$people[man]
```

In other word, having the reference `$people[man][person1]` how con i "level up" on the array?

Comment: You can't. Unfortunately, you don't have a reference to access the upper level of a multidimensional array. With the easier way, you need to pass that level to your function. Depending on your structure (if you're using classes, etc), you may set the array as an attribute of your class and access it from there.

Comment: what stops you to pass `$people[man]` directly in function and do things on need

Comment: I do not pass $people[man] because i want to create a function that automatically retrieve that, so i code less... I m creating a function to help me handle arrays, not just a single array structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass `$people['men']['person1']` to your function, there's no way how this function can know that this array has been nested within `$people['men']` outside of it.

> how can i "level up" on the array?

You can't. And what's more: **You shouldn't need to**.

The only reasonable answer here is: change the design of code to meet your requirements, try different approach, consider passing additional parameters to this function etc.

Comment: Ok, i can't... I was trying to do that so my function would have automatically retrieved the "upper" position without an additional parameter (=> code less!)

Answer (score 0):

**Alt aproach**

What you need is a class instead of just a functoin; consither this as the call:

```
(new my_class($people))->func($people[man][person1]);
```

You will be passing the full array to your instance of `my_class` so you can store that in a variable or pass it as reference.

Your class the, should look like this:

```
class my_class {

 private $my_people;

 public function __construct($outside_people) {
    $this->my_people = $outside_people;
 }

 public function func($person){
    .....
 }

}
```

Now you can access `$this->my_people` from the inside of your function.

**Another alt aproach**

Just pass the array in a seccond var. You will need to pass it by reference:

```
func($person, &$full_array){
....
}
```

Then call your function like this:

```
func($people[man][person1], $people);
```

Since $full_array is a reference to $people outside of the function you are able to modify the original array from the insides of your function.

Comment: Sorry but it's not what I m searching for, cause I m trying to create a class that help me handle generic arrays, I don't want to store the array because the arrays are in the "main" code, the class should "extend" the php native functions and let me do more with arrays coding less. Maybe the second approach you posted is the only possible, need to code some more calling the function but it is...

Comment: You need to pass your array by reference to your function then, I modified the original answer to reflect it.